# Create running number to a form using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

1. I want create a form with a reference number or running number for each form. For example, first form the reference number is "PPKT/01/14", second form is "PPKT/02/14", third form is "PPKT/03/14" and so on.
2. The "PPKT" is fix. "01,02,03,.." is running number. "14" is year.
3. This is the code that I've created. It works. My question is: How can I stop the running number "01,02,03,.." if year 2014 end. And I want to start back the running number as "01" for year 2015. Example "PPKT/01/15" Below the code is the database.

   ```
   <?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","info");
   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

   function number($str)
   {
   preg_match_all("/[0-9]/",$str, $num);
   $num = implode("",$num[0]);
   return $num;
   }

   //declare variable
   $x="PPKT";
   $y=date("y");

   $sql="Select mp_id, reference_no from information".
   " ORDER BY mp_id DESC";

   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
   { 
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       $mp_id=$row['mp_id'];
       $reference_no=$row['reference_no'];

           $mystr=$mp_id;
           $b=substr($mystr,0,2);

           $j=number($mystr)+1;
           $z=sprintf("%02s",$j);
           //$d=$b.$z;
   }
   else
   { 
   //will create if not in table
           //$b = $x;    
           $z=sprintf("%02s",1);
           //$d=$b.$z;
   }

   // output
   $reference_no="$x/$z/$y";
   echo "Reference Number => ".$reference_no;
   ?>
   ```
4. Database info:

   ```
   CREATE table information (
   mp_id int(4) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY'
   reference_no varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   name varchar(20) NOT NULL );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line:

```
$j=number($mystr)+1;
```

with a conditional statement that tests the year.  If year is different, then `$j` is 1, otherwise, you can add obtain `$j` by adding 1 to `$mystr` as in your original code.

New code would be:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{ 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $mp_id=$row['mp_id'];
    $reference_no=$row['reference_no'];

        $mystr=substr($reference_no,5,2);
        $ref_year=substr($reference_no,-2);

        if ($ref_year == $y) { // Checks if the year changed
          $j=number($mystr)+1;
        } else {
          $j=1;
        }

        $z=sprintf("%02s",$j);

}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Please explain a bit details. thank you